# How to set a default value for a specific column in which other columns interact with Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, pandas

I have a DataFrame that creates a CSV with this function:

```py
def create_data(date, place, value):
    can_spend = 190

    try:
        file = open(filename, 'r+')

        data_set = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=False)

        frame = pd.DataFrame(data_set, columns=['Left', 'Date', 'Place', 'Spent'])
        frame = frame.append({"Left": can_spend, "Date": date, "Place": place, "Spent": value}, ignore_index=True)
        frame['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(frame['Date'])
        frame['Week'] = frame['Date'].dt.weekofyear

        # write the data-set to the csv
        frame.to_csv(filename, index=None, header=True)
    except IOError:
        file = open(filename, "w")

        frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Left', 'Date', 'Place', 'Spent'])
        frame.to_csv(filename, index=None, header=True)
```

This DataFrame is going to be storing a small portion of my personal budget. I have a set spending limit that I want each each entry in the frame to subtract from based on the week (the spending limit will reset each week).
Here is how I add data to the DataFrame:

```py
def create_new_entry(self):
    get_date = input("Date: ")
    get_place = input("Place: ")
    get_amount = float(input("Amount: "))
    create_data(get_date, get_place, get_amount)
```

Here is how I would like the DataFrame to look:

```
"Left" column will default to the value of 190 each week

     Left        Date    Place  Spent  Week
0  146.69  2019-01-02  Walmart  43.31     1
1  92.46   2019-01-05  Kroger   54.23     1
2  72.46   2019-01-06  Kroger   20.00     1
# Here is where "Left" will reset on new week
3  170.00  2019-01-08  Kroger   20.00     2
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you add sample data and expected result? Will help a lot to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Valentino I updated the question with a barebones example of how I'd like it to look

Comment: I added how I am adding data to the DataFrame to better help @Valentino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with [groupby](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+groupby&oq=pandas+groupby&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0l2j69i60.4248j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [cumsum](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+cumsum&oq=pandas+cumsum&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.2675j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) with a single line of code. Do not add the `'Left'` column while reading and creating the dataframe (I mean, you can, but it will be overwritten anyway).

Suppose then that, after reading and first manipulation to create the useful `'Week'` column, your `df` is:

```
         Date    Place  Spent  Week
0  2019-01-02  Walmart  43.31     1
1  2019-01-05   Kroger  54.23     1
2  2019-01-06   Kroger  20.00     1
3  2019-01-08  Walmart  20.00     2
4  2019-01-09  Walmart  30.00     2
5  2019-01-10   Kroger  10.00     2
```

Then you can create the `'Left'` column like:

```
can_spend = 190

df['Left'] = df.groupby('Week').apply(lambda x : can_spend - x['Spent'].cumsum()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

And `df` will become:

```
         Date    Place  Spent  Week    Left
0  2019-01-02  Walmart  43.31     1  146.69
1  2019-01-05   Kroger  54.23     1   92.46
2  2019-01-06   Kroger  20.00     1   72.46
3  2019-01-08  Walmart  20.00     2  170.00
4  2019-01-09  Walmart  30.00     2  140.00
5  2019-01-10   Kroger  10.00     2  130.00
```

A brief explanation: `groupby` creates subsets of the dataframe, grouping rows with the same value in column `'Week'`. The `apply` method do the vectorized calculation to get the remaining amount for each subset (week). `reset_index(drop=True)` is needed otherwise the index builtd by `groupby` will not match with the index of `df`, raising an error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am getting this ValueError when creating the "Left" column: _Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1_

Comment: Are you using the `reset_index(drop=True)` at the end? I get this error if I don't pass the `drop=True` option.

Comment: Yes I am. I ended up getting rid of the error by adding the "Left" column and having `apply` append values to the column. Is there a way to be able to add entries out of order (out of date) and still keep the same "Left" total?

Comment: I also figured out the `Left` values will be null until the week counter increments. Can this be updated in real time as new entries are entered within the same week?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing now. I would investigate on the error. because with my solution the whole `'Left'` column is created and filled with the last line in a single step, so you will not have this problem.

Comment: How does your `create_data` function look in reference to my code?

Comment: I just copied your expected result without the `'Left'` column, and create it with my code. I cannot use your `create_data`, I don't have the original text file.

Comment: Whatever is causing that issue doesn't seem to hurt the week counter when it's above 1 so I can deal with that. Thanks for all the help!